# include own module does not work with firefox sdk require

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

for some reasons the following does code not work:

main.js:

```
var data = require('self').data;
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
var mediator = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
var self = require('self');

exports.main = function(options, callbacks)
{
    var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

    tabs.on("ready",
            function (activeTab)
            {
                activeTab.attach({contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("inject.js")]});
            }
        );
};
```

inject.js:

```
var test = require("test");
test.five();
```

test.js under root-addon-folder/lib:

```
exports.five = function ()
{
    window.alert("high five!");
};
```

reference to the turiral here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/reusable-modules.html
with newest changes: http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/01/25/changes-to-require-syntax/

I am using the online Builder from Mozilla.

Comment: The requirejs tag currently present on the question is not appropriate. ``require`` in Firefox's SDK is not the same as ``require`` provided by RequireJS.

Comment: ok, I think this sould be clear now, that firefox´s require is meant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `inject.js` is a content script. Content scripts cannot use `require`, only privileged modules such as `main.js` can.

There is no equivalent `require` mechanism for content scripts, but you can load script from multiple `data` files at once.

Just remove the `exports` bit from `test.js`, and place the file in the `data` folder:

```
function five() {
    window.alert("high five!");
}
```

Then change your `attach` call:

```
activeTab.attach({contentScriptFile: [
  self.data.url("test.js"),
  self.data.url("inject.js")
]});
```

Comment: thanks man, works fine! I am also passing data with self.port.on("handler", function)..